# Problemas ao usar SelectOneMenu primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Estou com um problema para atualizar os dados de um SelectOneMenu no primefaces, como sugere o código abaixo, possuo um botão que ao ser clicado, traz dados de um WebService e armazena em uma variavel de Devices em back-end e logo após, joga somente seus nomes para a lista deviceNames, isso occorre pois printo o Size da lista com os nomes e está OK, acontece que nada aparece no meu SelectOneMenu. já fiz muitas alterações porém até agora nada. Parece ser algo bem bobo mas não consigo achar o problema.

**Página XHTML**

```
<h:body>
    <p:messages autoUpdate="true"/>
    <h:form id="mainform">
        <p:commandButton id="button1" 
                         value="Configuração">
            <p:ajax listener="#{config.carregaSbcDevices}" update="panelAU"/>
        </p:commandButton>
        <p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true" id="panelAU">
            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{config.configSCBEsc}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione..." itemValue="" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{config.devicesName}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

**Bean config**

```
public void carregaSbcDevices() {
    if(this.devices == null) this.devices = new ArrayList<>();
    this.devices.clear();

    if(this.devicesName == null) this.devicesName = new ArrayList<>();
    this.devicesName.clear();

    session.getDevices(this.devices);
    for(SBCDevices device : this.devices) {
        this.devicesName.add(device.getTargetName());
    }

    System.out.println("Numero: " + this.devicesName.size());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problema Corrigido!**

Após pequenas tentativas diárias falhas, notei que os mesmos códigos feitos por outros desenvolvedores não apresentavam erro, ao buscar soluções nos packages que estava usando descobri o erro, os imports do `SessionScoped` e do `Named` (Utilizo este ao invés de `@ManagedBean(name = 'beanName')`. Portanto, solucionei fazendo as seguintes alterações:

**Alias do Bean:**

`@Named(value = "beanAgregadorDetalhe")`

**E o respectivo import:**

`import javax.inject.Named;`

**Escopo de Sessão:**

`@SessionScoped`

**E o respectivo import:**

`import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;`

Dessa forma os escopos funcionam perfeitamente agora e a página conversa normalmente com o bean sem a necessidade de variáveis estáticas. Quem estiver com problema de variáveis manipuladas em determinado escopo, **Cuidado com os imports!**

Answer (score 0):

Possivelmente o update do seu ajax não está encontrando o componente `panelAU`. Isso ocorre pois ao realizar a renderização na tela o primefaces adicionar o nome do form junto ao nome que foi definido.

Ou seja. Possivelmente o id do compontante `panelAU` está como: `mainform.panelAU`.

Troque esse trecho de código:

```
<p:ajax listener="#{config.carregaSbcDevices}" update="panelAU"/>
```

Para:

```
<p:ajax listener="#{config.carregaSbcDevices}" update="mainform.panelAU"/>
```

Caso mesmo assim não funcione. Inspecione o html gerado e coloque exatamente o id que foi gerado.

Comment: Boa tarde, primeiramente, obrigado pela ajuda.
Fiz a alteração agora porém com esta linha alterada recebo o seguinte erro:
**Cannot find component with expression "mainform.panelAU" referenced from "mainform:button1".**
Fiz a alteração para:
    <p:ajax listener="#{config.carregaSbcDevices}" update="mainform:panelAU"/>
Que é como aparece o id da div no html, a página roda mas continua não atualizando...

Comment: Você  inspecionou o elemento? Como está o id do select?

Comment: Peguei o html e o id está como 'mainform:selectOne' - este 'selectOne' é o id que eu coloquei agora no componente, e mesmo colocando update='mainform:selectOne' não retorna nada. Estou fazendo alguns testes com somente id, ou com id do form + id do componente.

Comment: Faça isso... Teste também colocar @form.  Para ver se ele atualiza.

Comment: Coloquei o @form e até agora nada. Tentei também com 'mainform:selectOne_panel' pois dentro da div 'selectOne' existe outra com o id 'selectOne_panel' que é criado no html e é onde fica os `<option>`.
Neste link abaixo possui o código HTML gerado:
**http://dontpad.com/htmlstackquestion**

Comment: Tente colocar a tag process="@form" no p:ajax

Comment: Tentei com o `@form` e `@parent` também, mas não houve mudanças também. Alterei a estrutura e agora tenho o Form, e logo abaixo o botão e o SelectOne, sem panel. Não houve melhoras, ainda estou tentando verificar o html mas aparentemente não tem nada sem ID... E está parecendo que o componente sofre o update mas não faz um get() novo na variável, constatei isso utilizando um p:commandRemote, e no onsuccess dele coloquei um alert. Será que pode ter algo a ver com a versão do JSF ou do NetBeans, etc??

Comment: Acabei de testar tb com <f:ajax ao invés de <p:ajax para ver se não era bug do primefaces ou algo assim, também usei o <h:selectOneMenu ao invés do <p:selectOneMenu. Mesmo assim o erro persistiu, me parece erro de lógica. Estranho isso não estão funcionando.

Comment: Recriei esta página do primefaces showcase: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/dropdown.xhtml
E o resultado foi este: http://tinypic.com/r/htwoxe/9 - Estranho não?? Creio que possa ser algo em meu primeface.

Comment: Estranho mesmo! qual versão você está utilizando?

Comment: Estava na 5.0 e alterei para a 6.0, esse da página era um erro de XML, alterei um parametro e funcionou, engraçado que a página da showcase funciona bem aqui. Agora fiz um teste, com um botão eu carrego tudo do webservice e deixo pronto, no outro eu jogo pra variavel da tela, seguindo o mesmo padrão do showcase. E o estranho é que ele traz 22 registros mas na hora de colocar esses registros na variável que vai pra tela, lança um NPE, como se alguma outra coisa zerasse essa variável. Amanhã posto mais, estou em semana de provas na facul. Mas obrigado por enquanto :D

Comment: Creio que achei o problema, separei o método em duas partes e dois botões, o primeiro popula a variavel `devices` que é a lista de objeto, e no outro botão, chama o método que traz os nomes dos objetos para `devicesName`. Ai é que está o problema, a variável `devices` está como nula no momento da segunda chamada. Parece que a página está como Request Scoped, mas na vdd está como ViewScoped... Creio que seja isto, só não sei como resolver, rs.

Comment: @Ricardo conseguiu achar uma solução?

Comment: Tentei diversas formas de Scopo porém, a solução, mesmo que momentânea, foi utilizar variaves `static`, mesmo sabendo que não seja a melhor forma. Após concluir boa parte da aplicação voltarei a esturar essa questão. Mas de momento é isto, ja que não obtive nenhuma outra informação em documentação. Obrigado.